# Get facebook page access token with all permission that an fb app has granted

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

I have an fb app that also has `pages_messaging` permission to post private reply.
I created permanent page token following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/

But my page access token does not have `pages_messaging` permission and am not able to post private reply from my page using fb graph api using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies/

Am also trying this on fb api explorer tool and its giving permission issue that you are missing `pages_messaging` permission to perform this action

[image]

Please guide me on this

Comment: Did the user token you used to request the page token have it in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe it may be issue with user token. i will try with admin user token